# Why isn't the Dirichlet Function Riemann Integrable?

Tags: analysis

Can we find out the upper and lower sums based solely on the domain [a,b] ?

Comment: Yes, just use the fact that any non-empty subinterval must contain both a rational and an irrational. So the lower sum must be 0, and the upper sum must be 1.

Comment: For any partition of $[a,b]$, the upper sum is 1 and the lower sum is 0.

Comment: Can someone please explain why? I am aware each interval will contain rational and irrational but why is the upper/lower sums then 0 and 1?. (Why is the supremum 1 and infimum 0?)
Also what if we modify the function to says x instead of 1? Is is still 0 and 1?

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd post the precise definition and notation you are using for Riemann integrability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the interval $[0,1]$, let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\in\mathbb Q\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
For any partition $0=x_0<x_1<\ldots <x_n=1$, the Riemann upper sum is
$$U_{\mathbf x}=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})\sup_{x_{i-1}<x<x_i}f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})=1$$
because in each interval $(x_{i-1},x_i)$ there is some rational $q\in(x_{i-1},x_i)$ and hence the supremum is $\sup_{x_{i-1}<x<x_i}f(x)\ge f(q)=1$ (and of course it is not larger than $1$). Likewise, the lower sum is 
$$L_{\mathbf x}=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})\inf_{x_{i-1}<x<x_i}f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})\cdot 0=0$$
beacuse the existence of irrationals $\alpha\in(x_{i-1},x_i)$ cause $\inf_{x_{i-1}<x<x_i}f(x)\le f(\alpha)=0$ (and of course it is not below $0$).

If we consider 
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{if }x\in\mathbb Q\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
instead, the situation hardly changes: Since there are rationals arbitrarily close to the right ends of the intervals, we have in fact that $\sup_{x_{i-1}<x<x_i}=x_i$; thus the upper sum is the same as for the identity function itself and therefore tends to $\frac12$ as the partition gets finer. But the lower sum is still $0$.